# Ribbon won't stay pinned

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

I'm using OneNote and the ribbon would set back to hidden mode upon every new window open.

I can't seem to make it permanently stay pinned. I have to either press `Ctrl+F1` or manually show the ribbon every time.

Comment: [in this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-onenote/remember-show-tabs-setting-in-onenote-ribbon/6b257762-0d19-4e5a-8f2b-5a1bdb6c4280) it seems it will not stay pinned across sessions, but you can use the `show tabs` feature in the current session

Answer (score 1):

I've sort of solved it by deleting everything in the Registry about OneNote.

[How to restore OneNote 2007 to its default state](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925899).
Just the step#1 worked.